# Blender model deformation when moving with bone

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

I am a noob at Blender and I am beginning to learn the basics... I am attempting to rig a halo spartan for animation, and when I try and pair the helmet to the rig (rig I got online), and when I go to rotate/interact with the head bone, the Helmet deforms and the mesh gets twisted and weird... I have no idea how to fix this, I've looked everything up related to this issue but no luck... here are some screen shots and the file which I am working on... Any help is GREATLY appreciated!(I haven't rigged the visor yet)

EDIT: also the helmet has an internal head structure to it and when I move the head model with a bone(i.e rotating the head bone it or moving the rig), the inner mesh drifts and clips through the helmet model... how can I eliminate the mesh from drifting? thanks

EDIT: I have uploaded a new edit of the file which includes the model's bones that come with the model if that helps

[image]
[image]
[image]

FILE HERE:    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pfldMmA9ICe0En3kVihqZ727_TIbnW5j/view?usp=sharing

Comment: we can't download your file because it asks for authorization, please use for example https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Sorry about that lol. here's a link to it     https://pasteall.org/blend/5b7a2d77dd4d4e1085a6cfd455734e2f

Comment: there is no object in your file, only the armature. Do you want to only parent the helmet? If it is supposed to only be parented to one bone, select the helmet, shift select the bone, switch the armature to Pose mode, then ctrl P > Bone. Because right here it looks like you have parented With Automatic Weight, therefore several bones influence the object...

Comment: Thanks for responding! Im having a bit of trouble when selecting the bones... in object mode, I select the helmet, then I shift select the armature, but it selects the entire armature... stupid question but how do I only select the head bone? I can select just the head mode in pose mode.. thanks for you time!                                                                         EDIT: I don't know why there aren't any objects in the file... I directly uploaded the file to the website stated above... ill try and fix that lol thanks again

Comment: select the helmet, shift select the armature, then switch to Pose mode, you'll see that the helmet is still selected, and press ctrl P

Comment: hmm I still seem to get the deformation even when pairing the helmet to just the head bone... If it helps I also uploaded an updated file which contains the helmets head/neck bone structure if that helps... when I move the helmet's head bone it moves properly.. is there a way I can pair the helmet's bone the the armature's head bone? just an idea... thanks again for helping me out!

Comment: I believe I have reached success. Instead of pairing it woth automatic weights I paired it to "Bone". that fixed it... unless I should pair it with automatic weights..... thanks

Comment: well, that's what I told you  ;)

Comment: I see ahahahahahaha Thanks soooo much for the help! it really means alot!

Answer (score 1):

Don't parent *With Automatic Weight*, because it will give influence to several bones and your helmet will bend, instead parent to > *Bone*: Select the helmet, <kbd>shift</kbd> select the armature, then switch the armature to *Pose* mode, you'll see that the helmet is still selected, and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone*. Parent *With Automatic Weight* is good for organic objects, but for machines, robots, etc, use a direct parent to bone.

Answer (score 1):

Select vertices that deformed by this transformation and remove these vertices from all groups. Reassign vertices to the group that should affect them.

[image]

Hope this helps someone.